# Счетчик баллов Laravel

Tags: laravel

Пишу небольшую викторину на Laravel(на странице 1 вопрос) при переходе на следующую страницу проверяет ответ и добавляет бал.
Реализовал через сессии

```
public function addRating()
    {
        $rating = session('rating');
        ++$rating;
        session()->put('rating', $rating);
        return $rating;
    }
```

Столкнулся с проблемой накрутки баллов(при возврате на предыдущую страницу
Кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: храните номер вопроса и полученный по нему балл. без этих ваших ++

Comment: просто в базе? Там будет или +1 или 0

Comment: вы же сказали, что сессию используете

Comment: правильно, каждый раз при верном ответе в сессию записываю рейтинг, увеличенный на единицу

Comment: А вы записывайте не ++, а верные ответы. Или массив с ключами-id верных ответов (два одинаковых ключа быть не может). В итоге считаете количество - и готово.

Comment: Ок попробую так